# Como obtener un objeto con la interface Optional?

Tags: java, java-8, optional

Trato de obtener un objeto della clase Persona (clase ya creada) pero quiero obtenerlo con la interfaz Optional, porque el objeto podrìa o no encontrarse en un Set de Personas.
El metodo serìa asì:

```
public Optional<Persona> getPersona(Persona pe) 
{
    Optional<Persona> user = Optional.ofNullable(null);

    Predicate<Persona> ver = umano -> 
    {       
        boolean b = false;
        for(Persona i: personas) // personas es el Set de personas ya creado
        {
            if(i.equals(pe)) 
            b = true;
        }
        return b;
    };
    user.filter(ver);
    if(user.isPresent())
        user.get();
    return user;
}
```

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es tu pregunta. Como obtener un objeto de `Optional` ya lo has puesto: `.isPresent`, `.get`. ¿Preguntas cómo hacer un método que mire si la `Persona pe` existe en `Set personas` y devolver un optional? ¿O cuál es el problema exactamente?

Comment: esos metodos los hice tratando de restituir un Optional de Persona

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te confundiste un poco, te aclaro varias cosas:

- Optional no es una interfaz.... es una pseudo-mónada

Siempre puedes usar el Strem API que ya se encarga de devolverte el valor opcional.

Suponiendo que hayas inicializado tu lista de personas y que sepas a cual vas a buscar

```
List<Persona> personas = Arrays.asList(new Persona("Kevin",22),new Persona("Ruslan",33),new Persona("Kevin",45));
```

puedes definir tu método de una sola línea `buscarPersona` como:

```
public Optional<Persona> buscarPersona(String personaABuscar,List<Persona> personas) {
  Objects.requireNotNull(personas, "agrega una lista de personas para buscar en ella");
  Objects.requireNonNull(personaABuscar,"especifica un nombre para buscarlo");
  return personas.stream().filter(persona->personaABuscar.equalsIgnorecase(persona.getNombre())).findFirst();
}
```

y usar el resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
String personaABuscar = "Kevin";
Optional<Persona> hallado = buscarPersona(personaABuscar,personas);
System.out.println("Se encontró a "+hallado.get().orElse("nadie :'v"));
if(hallado.isPresent()){
  Persona elKevin = hallado.get();
  System.out.println("hola soy " + elKevin.getNombre() + " y tengo " + elKevin.getEdad() + "años");
}
```

- Nota: hice todo de memoria, pero seguramente te sevirá de guía de como usar el Optional para obtener valores a conveniencia.